# Where on earth to spark read local file when running an application in client mode

Tags: apache-spark

I am deploying a spark **Standalone** cluster.172.16.133.15 is a Master with two Workers all in one machine, and it's deployed in ubuntu14.10.

As the doc says, I can run applications with both "client mode" or "cluster mode".

My questions is:

1) Where to load file when running an application in client mode (in windows machine)??

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test")
                                .setMaster("172.16.133.15")
                                .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "client");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
String path = "file:///C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\demo\\1530699196271";
JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles(path);

 JavaPairRDD<String, String> transformed = rdd.mapToPair(tuple2 ->{
       String fname = tuple2._1();
       String content = tuple2._2();
       content = YUVSimpleTrans.transform(content);
       return new Tuple2<>(fname, content);
 });
 transformed.saveAsTextFile("file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/demo/out");
```

when I run the codes, I got exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get 
file permissions : java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null ls -F C:\Users\Me\Desktop\demo\1530699196271\split_0.yuv
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:762)
....
test.sparker4m.Sparker4mApplication.main(Sparker4mApplication.java:51)
...
```

I don't know why it use "ls -F".

So I build a cifs directory with samba in 172.16.133.15, and upload all files in the direcotry "/usr/local/test/1530699196271", and modify the "path" variable, then it throw an exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/usr/local/test/1530699196271
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:321)
... 31 more
```

I very confused that what the hell the "client mode" working.

---

2. Does "cluster mode" upload jar file to the Master when use "spark-submit"?

if it's true, if I run my code use "spark-submit" with cluster mode (upload files 
 to Master(172.16.133.15) which has two workers ) will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From exactly the same place as in any other mode. It is resolved on each node (driver node and each executor node).

Therefore if you use local path each executor will attempt to read a local file on its own file system in a give path. Obviously there is no `"file:///C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\demo\\1530699196271"` on your Ubuntu nodes - therefore failure is expected behavior.

Either use a distributed file system or homogeneous cluster with copy of the input on each node on the same path (clearly not applicable for mixed Windows and Linux nodes).

Comment: so, does it mean the file(s) should be accessible on all nodes , **including** the outside machine which runs  a "dirver program" ? It's a little weird to understand...and does it mean if I supply a NFS path, things will be done?

Comment: @W.X In client mode yes (the driver is not "outside"), in cluster mode no (driver runs on the cluster, not the machine that submits app).